# Can you remove DataStore from an Amplify project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

When playing around with the Amplify settings, I discover the Amplify Studio.
There you could use DataStore for the existing project but that polluted my generated types for the project.

I can manually delete all `_version` and other keys, but when running `amplify codegen` -> the unwanted keys will be back.

I want to remove DataStore from my project but I can't find how?

Comment: What about going to [Amplify console][1](this is eu-central-1 region, select your region), selecting your app, selecting backend environment and there is option 'delete' from dropdown menu?
  [1]: https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/amplify/

Comment: ```amplify codegen``` generates code based on ```amplify/backend/api/project_name/schema.graphql``` isn't it enough if you remove redundant fields from there?

Comment: You can also run ```amplify api remove``` in your project root folder

Comment: @Chris yeah I deleted the api and created a new one. That fixed the infusion of DataStore in my application. You can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `amplify api remove` in your project root folder.

The other option might be to remove backend from [Amplify Console](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/amplify)(this is eu-central-1 region, select your region), select your app, select backend environment and there is option 'delete' from dropdown menu

Answer (score 3):

I was recently able to accomplish this by doing the following:

1. First run: `amplify update api`
2. Select from one of the below mentioned services: `GraphQL`
3. Select a setting to edit: `Disable conflict detection`
4. Update API: `amplify push`

After the update the `_version` and `_lastChangedAt` fields were still on the DynamoDB objects, but you can manually remove those if you want them gone.